# JAVA_HOME env still not defined correctly windows 10

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

So recently I've been trying to set up a project using maven. After I installing the binary zip, I added it to my path by adding `M2_HOME` as a var name and `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.2` as the var value in my **System Environment Variables**. To confirm, this does exist:

[image]

Then I added `JAVA_HOME` as a var name and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19` as the var value to my **System Env Variables** as well:

[image]

Now, whenever I try running `mvn -version` or even `mvn` from terminal that is ran as admin and without admin permissions, I get:

```
C:\Users\67444>mvn -verison
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

C:\Users\67444>
```

Note: Before I added JAVA_HOME, when I ran `mvn package` I got a compilation error saying that the compiler wasn't figured, meaning that marven was installed and working. So I decided to add JAVA_HOME and now it fully stopped working for some reason.

Other Note:
I have these two values in **System Path**:

[image]

I tried:

Removing both environment variables and re-adding them
Fully re-installing Maven and following the steps agains

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: My Path:
[image]

Edit: Request by g00se:

```
C:\Users\67444>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin

C:\Users\67444>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenJDK\jre-8.0.292.10-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.292.10-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.362.09-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\Programs\Python;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\67444\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Roaming\npm;";C:\Program Files\nodejs\";C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\67444\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\67444\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;

C:\Users\67444>mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

C:\Users\67444>
```

UPDATE:
Removing `JAVA_HOME` from my environment vars in both system and user result in this screen:
[image]

But adding JAVA_HOME breaks it. Why?

Also there's these following sequence of commands I tried:
[image]

Comment: Did you try `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from the same prompt you're running maven?

Comment: @matt 
```C:\Users\67444>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19

C:\Users\67444>
```
in other words, yes

Comment: What about `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version` ie is jkd-19 the correct root of your jdk?

Comment: Also check `echo %PATH%` and make sure Maven and Java are right in that

Comment: After changing the environment have you ended the box and reopened it?

Comment: @g00se i reedited original post, and yes, it's in path

Comment: @khmarbasie yes, i think. elaborate on what u mean

Comment: Can you post what you get at the command line? NB after edits to env vars, you will need a *new* instance of cmd.exe in otder to see your changes

Comment: 1. check which exactly `mvn` you are running (in user home... (cmd: `where mvn`, in gitbash even better `which mvn`)) 2. clean your path from (jre) java 8 (first entry..all conflicting;)

Comment: @g00se exact same error after env var changes even in a new instance of cmd and restarting comp

Comment: It's not clear what is happening right now. Does `mvn --version` run and give you a valid path? does `java --version` run and use the correct java? Note, you don't really need the correct java on your path as long as JAVA_HOME points to the correct JDK then you're fine. What error are you getting when you try using mvn to compile something?

Comment: *Make sure that the 19 jdk is FIRST in PATH*. At the moment it seems to be Java 8. First entry should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` Could we please see the output of the following (posted as formatted code): `C:\Users\67444>echo %JAVA_HOME%;echo %PATH%;mvn -version`

Comment: Probably the best way to test this is to use the [quickstart archetype](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) that way we don't have to worry about an error with your pom.xml

Comment: @matt running `mvn --version` yields the JAVA_HOME error. `java --version` says --version is unrecognized, but `java -version` is recognized. Also I am unable to execute this command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4` as anything following `mvn` will yield the JAVA_HOME ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix:
Don't be an idiot like me, double check your JDK. Although I had a jdk-19 installing in my Program Files, it only had 1 folder, `lib`, which was **empty**

What I did:

I just removed that and installed latest JDK (jdk-20) although just reinstall JDK if you're an idiot like me